# Upgrading eclipselink 2.4 in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, eclipselink

Hi I upgraded Eclipse link to 2.4. But I get this output.
I am concerned about this message: "(Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504)"

Does this mean I am using the 2.3 library again?

```
In-place deployment at /Users/danielrojas/Dropbox/ToursysFunctional/build/web
Initializing...
deploy?DEFAULT=/Users/danielrojas/Dropbox/ToursysFunctional/build/web&name=Toursys&     contextroot=/Toursys&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.x 
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception    [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504):    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [WebApplication1PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field userRoles] from the entity class [class jpa.Users] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.. Please see server.log for more details.
/Users/danielrojas/Dropbox/ToursysFunctional/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1035: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this means you are using the old version. You probably missed a jar or forgot to delete the old ones.

Here is a short step-by-step explanation how to update EclipseLink in Glassfish:

1. Download the EclipseLink OSGI Bundle from http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/. The current version is 2.5.1 and the file you would download is `EclipseLink 2.5.1 OSGi Bundles Zip (19 MB)`
2. Go to  `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/modules` and delete the following files:

   - org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar
   - org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar
   - org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar
   - org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar
   - org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
   - org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar
   - javax.persistence.jar
3. Open the downloaded ZIP file and extract everything starting with `org.eclipse.persistence` but not containing `source` (these are the sources, your probably don't need them) and the file `javax.persistence_2xxx.jar` to the folder `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/modules`
4. Restart Glassfish and you are done.